# how update source on standalone computer with hg?

Tags: mercurial

I use mercurial on a standalone computer. I have also made some small changes of the source code on this computer. Now I want to update this code with a new version that I can bring to this computer on a CD or usb-stick as a gziped tar file. How do I do this update in the best way, and keep my changes of the standalone source.

Update: I forgot to mention that the files on the USB-stick is not from a mercurial database, they are just a bunch of source-files from a perforce controlled source tree. We have mercurial only on the standalone computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the remote machine (first time):

```
hg clone {path_to_repository} {path_on_usb_stick}
```

On subsequent runs:

```
cd {path_to_repository}
hg push {path_on_usb_stick}
```

Then on the local machine:

```
cd {path_to_repository}
hg commit
hg pull {path_on_usb_stick}
hg up
```

At some point, hg might warn you about multiple heads, which means there are conflicts that you need to resolve by running `hg merge`.

To get your changes from the local machine to the repo server, you reverse the procedure.

Comment: I have tried this but can't create a repository with the new files because they will be unrelated to the repository on the standalone machine.

Comment: I finally understand that I also must have a hg repository on the original machine. So I will create it and try to remember to administrate it when perfoce is updating the files, and then I follow your recipe when transfering files to standalone computer.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can simply copy the files from the hg-less machine onto the USB stick, and then do `hg addremove` and `hg commit` on the stick, finally `hg pull` the USB stick's repo into your local repo and `hg up` it. This doesn't carry over removed files though, but other than that, it should manage changes nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just put Mercurial binaries and a .hg repo right on the flash drive.  Then you can push/pull to/from it at home, and copy atop it at work.